# Unable to test component that exists within React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have my routes defined in my app file like so. I am using jest and enzyme to test, however, my snapshots are never matching up. I'm manually injecting props into the component upon rendering within my test, but the snapshot seems to always just output an empty div.

Below I've attached:

- The error log
- Component
- Component.Spec
- Routes file

## Error Log

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

  37 |         // ).toJSON()
  38 |         // expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
> 39 |         expect(wrapper.find('test')).to.have.length(0)

  40 |     });
  41 |
  42 | });
```

## Test

```
import Dashboard from '../src/Dashboard/components/Dashboard';
const wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard />);
console.log(wrapper.find('.test'))
// const DashboardComponent = withRouter(Dashboard);

// Snapshot for Home React Component
describe('>>>D A S H B O A R D --- Snapshot',()=>{
    it('+++capturing Snapshot of Dashboard', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('test')).to.have.length(0)
    });
```

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/containers/DashboardContainer';
import Budget from './Budget/containers/BudgetContainer'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Dashboard />
            <Route path="/editBudget" component={Budget} />
            <Route path="/settings" component={Budget} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My Dashboard component looks like the following (Renders two child components)

## Dashboard

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="test"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Axnyff I've updated the OP with way less code.

Comment: It should be .toHaveLength instead of .to.have.length

Comment: @Axnyff ok, great. My original problem is in my Dashboard component, I have child components rendered.. <Child1 /> <Child2 />. What is the standard for ensuring these components get rendered or what is the approach to go about testing child components?

Comment: If you are using shallow it will only render one level of component. If you need to render everything, you need to use mount instead

Comment: @Axnyff but say I am shallow rendering, the markup will still appear, no?
expect(wrapper.children().contains(<Header/>)).toEqual(true);

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={Main}>
         <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
         <Route path="/editBudget" component={Budget} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Please use the Indexroute to show the default component to be rendered on the page.